# with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s: get error: AttributeError: __exit__

Tags: python

I have a socket server program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# Author:sele


import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break

            conn.sendall(data)
```

when I run it in my terminal:

there get error:

> sele-MacBook-Pro:test01 ldl$ ./tests02-server.py
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "./tests02-server.py", line 11, in 
>           with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
>       AttributeError: **exit**

why there get this error?

Comment: You are using Python 2.x, I suppose?  Socket objects didn't get the context manager functionality needed to support `with` until 3.x.

Comment: I see that the above is the example code from the Python 3.x documentation for the socket class. As jasonharper says, that doesn't work in Python 2.x. The "#!/usr/bin/env python" hashbang line defaults to Python2, so if both Python2 and Python3 are installed, you'll get Python2. The hashbang line should read  "#!/usr/bin/env python3".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` with `with`.  So that a `with` statement can clean up the resource it is working with, that resource's object has to have an `__exit__` method.  What `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` returns obviously has no `__exit__` method for `with` to call, hence this error.

Per @jasonharper, it sounds like this would work if you were using Python3.  Maybe you copied Python3 code from somewhere, but are running Python 2.7?

Answer (score 4):

You probably already figured this out, but if you run the script from terminal in the following manner, you will not get the error: ~$ python3 echo-server.py